# return list of arrays

Tags: arrays, list, tcl, tk-toolkit

where is the difference in TCL TK with list and array ?
I created a list of 3 arrays.

like this one in a loop

```
set x($idx) 1
incr idx
```

and later i want to return the "ret" object

```
list set ret { $x $x2 $x3 }
```

and parse them again with

```
lassign $data x x2 x3
```

but this wont work... :( 
could someone please help me again.. damn tcl tk... :D:D

correct me if im not right, its not possible to build a 2dim list or array ?

Answer (score 2):

Your array is called **x** - you can refer to its elements by `set x(1)` , `set x(2)` etc. $x2 and $x3 have no meanings in this case.

If you want a 2 dimensional array, you can simulate it in TCL as follows:

```
set a(1,1) 0 ;# set element 1,1 to 0
set a(1,2) 5 ;# set element 1,2 to 5
```

It might be easier if you just use a list of lists

```
set l1 [list a b c]
set l2 [list d e f]
set lol [list $l1 $l2]
```

Comment: is it possible to add elements to the list via a loop ? like append ?

Comment: Yes, very easy. Use a for e.g. for {set i 1} {$i <= 10} {incr i} { lappend l1 $i }

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array get/set` to pass arrays as procedure arguments / return values. For example:

```
proc someProc {arr} {
  array set x $arr
  set x(5) 0
  return [array get x]
}
```

Example of usage:

```
% set a(0) -1
% set a(1) 1

% parray a
a(0) = -1
a(1) = 1

% array set b [someProc [array get a]]

% parray b
b(0) = -1
b(1) = 1
b(5) = 0
```

Comment: From Tcl 8.5 onwards, you can pass around array-like values as dictionaries (manipulated via the `dict` command). The `array get` command produces a dictionary, and the `array set` command consumes one.